# Merge values in two nodes of linked list

Tags: c, stack, queue, nodes

I have a squeue (combination of stack and queue). I have a function called mergeFront that's job is supposed to merge the first two nodes into one. For example if the front node is "alpha" and the second node is "beta" they should be merged into "alphabeta".

```
void mergeFront(struct Squeue* squeue){
    struct Node* temp;
    char *string;
    char *tempstring=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    temp = squeue->first;
    temp = temp->next;
    string = squeue->first->val;
    strcpy(tempstring, string);
    string = temp->val;
    strcat(tempstring, string);
    squeue->first->next->val=tempstring;
    temp = squeue->first;
    squeue->first = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    free(tempstring);
}
```

When I `free(tempstring)` in the last line, that first node now becomes null (assuming because I have free'd what the value was pointing to). If I get rid of the `free(tempstring)` it works well but there is a memory leak. How can I do this while freeing the memory properly?

The struct of nodes is as follows

```
struct Node{
    char* val;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};
```

After taking the code given by @ikegami my code is as follows :

```
void mergeFront(struct Squeue* squeue){

  struct Node* node1 = squeue->first;  if (node1 == NULL) return;
  struct Node* node2 = node1->next;    if (node2 == NULL) return;

  char* str1 = node1->val;  size_t str1len = strlen(str1);
  char* str2 = node2->val;  size_t str2len = strlen(str2);
  char* merged = malloc(str1len + str2len + 1);
  memcpy(merged, str1,str1len + 1);
  strcpy(merged+str1len, str2);

  node1->val = NULL;
  free(node1->val);
  node1->val = merged;

  node1->next = node2->next;

  node2->val = NULL;
  free(node2->val);
  free(node2);
```

}

It is fully functioning except I am still getting 10bytes of leaked memory in 1 block. Any clues as to where I can find this?

Comment: You probably want to free the 2 strings pointed to by `first->val` and `first->next->val` and not `tempstring`.

Comment: Indeed, and don't free `tempstring`! You're still using the referenced memory.

Comment: ...and when you do free it, it will most definitely NOT make any pointers to it NULL--you'll have to do that yourself. This is C, not some hand-holding beginner's language :-)

Comment: RE your edit: You can't set a pointer to `NULL` _before_ you `free` it! If you feel you must set to `NULL` do it after you `free` it.

Comment: `node1->val = NULL; free(node1->val);` makes no sense. It's the same as just `node1->val = NULL;`

Comment: If i remove the node1->val = NULL it gives a freeing error when i free the value... I'm guessing I made an error when initializing the node as I only malloc'd memory for the node itself and not for the char pointer

Comment: That would indeed be a problem. Something like `node->val = strdup("...");` would fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void mergeFront(struct Squeue* squeue) {
    /* Make sure we have at least two nodes. */
    struct Node* node1 = squeue->first;  if (node1 == NULL) return;
    struct Node* node2 = node1->next;    if (node2 == NULL) return;

    /* Create the combined string. */
    char* str1 = node1->val;  size_t str1len = strlen(str1);
    char* str2 = node2->val;  size_t str2len = strlen(str2);
    char* merged = malloc(str1len + str2len + 1);
    memcpy(merged, str1, str1len);
    strcpy(merged+str1len, str2);

    /* Replace the first node's string with the combined string. */
    free(node1->val);
    node1->val = merged;

    deleteNode(squeue, node2);
}
```

Helpers:

```
void deleteNode(struct Squeue* squeue, struct Node* node) {
    if (node->prev == NULL)
        squeue->first = node->next;
    else
        node->prev->next = node->next;

    if (node->next == NULL)
        squeue->last = node->prev;
    else
        node->next->prev = node->prev;

    free(node->val);
    free(node);       
}
```

Notes:

- I didn't free the memory pointed by `tempstring` (now called `merged`) because it's still being used (by `squeue->first->val`)!
- Don't guess at how much memory you need! Calculate it if necessary.
- `* sizeof(char)` is useless as `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.
- The above code requires C99 support because it mixes declarations and code. It can easily be converted into more backwards-compatible code (at the expense of readability).
- I used more variables than I needed in the hopes of making the code crystal clear.
- Tested.

---

Since you're calling this a "stack-queue", it would make more sense to use stack and queue operations.

```
void mergeFront(struct Squeue* squeue) {
    struct Node* node1 = shift(squeue);
    if (node1 == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    struct Node* node2 = shift(squeue);
    if (node2 == NULL) {
        unshift(squeue, node1);
        return;
    }

    char* str1 = node1->val;  size_t str1len = strlen(str1);
    char* str2 = node2->val;  size_t str2len = strlen(str2);
    node1->val = realloc(node1->val, str1len + str2len + 1);
    strcpy(node1->val + str1len, node2->val);

    freeNode(node2);
    unshift(squeue, node1);
}
```

Helpers:

```
void freeNode(struct Node* node) {
    free(node->val);
    free(node);
}

struct Node* shift(struct Squeue* squeue) {
    struct Node* node = squeue->first;
    if (node == NULL)
        return NULL;

    squeue->first = node->next;
    if (node->next == NULL)
        squeue->last = NULL;
    else {
        node->next->prev = NULL;
        node->next = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}

struct Node* pop(struct Squeue* squeue) {
    struct Node* node = squeue->last;
    if (node == NULL)
        return NULL;

    squeue->last = node->prev;

    if (node->prev == NULL)
        squeue->first = NULL;
    else {
        node->prev->next = NULL;
        node->prev = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}

void unshift(struct Squeue* squeue, struct Node* node) {
    if (squeue->first == NULL) {
        squeue->first = node;
        squeue->last = node;
    } else {
        node->next = squeue->first;
        squeue->first = node;
    }
}

void push(struct Squeue* squeue, struct Node* node) {
    if (squeue->last == NULL) {
        squeue->first = node;
        squeue->last = node;
    } else {
        node->prev = squeue->last;
        squeue->last = node;
    }
}
```

Tested.

Comment: I tried implementing the solution with realloc, however i am getting a segfault. When debugging I believe it arrises in the realloc line. Also your memcpy is missing the last argument... I believe it should be str1len + 1?

Comment: After some digging. It is the free(node2->val) that is causing the problems. It gives the error free : invalid pointer

Comment: I don't have a copy of the realloc code I had posted, so I can't comment. (I realized it leaked when the program runs out of memory, so I deleted it. Then again, both the posted solution and the relalloc solution segfault when the program runs out of memory...) /// Fixed the `memcpy` line. No need to copy the NUL that will get overwritten a second later. /// `free(node2->val)` should be there. Maybe `node2` wasn't properly built in the first place?

Comment: Just realized it was a double-linked list. Adjusted answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do:

1. Allocate space for the new string
2. Merge the 2 old strings into the new string
3. Delete the 2 old strings
4. Delete the first node, and update first node
5. Assign the new string to the new first node

-

```
void mergeFront(struct Squeue* squeue){
    // Make sure there are at least 2 nodes
    if (NULL == squeue->first || NULL == squeue->first->next) {
        return;
    }

    // 1. Allocate space for the new string
    char *tempstring = malloc(strlen(squeue->first->val) +
                              strlen(squeue->first->next->val) + 1);
    if (NULL == tempstring) {
        // Out of memory
        return;
    }

    // 2. Merge the 2 old strings into the new string
    sprintf(tempstring, "%s%s", squeue->first->val, squeue->first->next->val);

    // 3. Delete the 2 old strings
    free(squeue->first->val);
    free(squeue->first->next->val);

    // 4. Delete the first node, and update first node
    struct Node* temp = squeue->first;
    squeue->first = squeue->first->next;
    squeue->first->prev = NULL;
    free(temp);

    // 5. Assign the new string to the new first node
    squeue->first->val = tempstring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems odd

```
squeue->first->next->val=tempstring;
temp = squeue->first;
squeue->first = temp->next;
free(temp);
free(tempstring);
```

first you allocate tempstring and assign a pointer val to point to it but then later you free it making what val points to invalid.

seems you should skip the `free(tempstring)`

in order to merge the two nodes. first check the length of both strings to allocate enough space instead of assuming 100 is enough. allocate a buffer that can contain both strings plus the ending \0 i.e. use strlen() on both strings and add a 1.

thereafter strcpy/strcat both values to that buffer.

then free the strings that the first and second nodes point to

then assign the first node to point to this new node

and then set the pointers in the first node to eliminate the second, do not forget to free the second node. i.e. each node is two allocations, one for the node itself and one for the string it holds.

Comment: This is my problem! If i remove the free(tempstring) then I am stuck with a memory leak. This is where my confusion arises